# I am looking to print "worms" from a set just once. Is there a way to do that?

Tags: python

This is my script so far, There is a file we are given to open and sort through. When I print the results it prints the names of the worms like 10-12 times per worm. is there a way to make them only display once? I would greatly appreciate any help you could provide.

```
from __future__ import print_function
'''

Week Two Assignment 1 - File Processing
'''

'''
Complete the script below to do the following:
1) Add your name, date, assignment number to the top of this script
2) Open the file redhat.txt 
   a) Iterate through each line of the file
   b) Split eachline into individual fields (hint str.split() method)
   c) Examine each field of the resulting field list
   d) If the word "worm" appears in the field then add the worm name to the set of worms
   e) Once you have processed all the lines in the file
      sort the set 
      iterate through the set of worm names
      print each unqiue worm name 
3) Submit
   NamingConvention: lastNameFirstInitial_Assignment_.ext
   for example:  hosmerC_WK2-1_script.py
                 hosmerC_WK2-2_screenshot.jpg
   A) Screenshot of the results in WingIDE
   B) Your Script
'''
import os

SCRIPT_NAME    = "Week Two Assignment 1 - File Processing"
SCRIPT_VERSION = "Version 1.0"
SCRIPT_AUTHOR  = "Author: Brandon Holman"
SCRIPT_DATE = "January 20 2021"

print()
print(SCRIPT_NAME)
print(SCRIPT_VERSION)
print(SCRIPT_AUTHOR)
print(SCRIPT_DATE)
print()


uniqueWorms = set()

with open("redhat.txt", 'r') as logFile:
    for eachLine in logFile:
        ''' your code starts here '''
        
       line = eachLine.split():

       for field in line:
           if 'Worm' in field:
               uniqueWorms.add(field)
       for worms in sorted(uniqueWorms):
           print(worms)
     
                
        print("Script Complete")
```

Comment: Read about `nested loops` and make sure that you place your `print` into the appropriate level.

Answer (score 1):

Process the list of worms only when you're all done with the file.

```
for eachLine in logFile:
    
    print(eachLine)
     
    fields = eachLine.split()
    for field in fields:
        if field.lower().find('worm')!= -1:
            uniqueWorms.append(field.lower())

# You're all done reading the file and collecting worms.
# NOW you can print the results
uniqueWorms = sorted(uniqueWorms)
for worm in uniqueWorms:
    print(worm)
```

Comment: With the fixed indentation it gave me an error builtins.AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Right -- you still need to fix that part.  Do you want to add an element to a set, or append to a list?  Your original code is also inconsistent in this way.  You got away with it because the first loop iteration converted the set to a list.

Comment: so I made uniqueWorms an empty set and I want to put each different name for a worm inside the set and then print the names of those worms, when I do that it prints the names like 10 times each

Comment: You made it an empty set, converted it to a list with `sorted`, and appended to the list.
"10 times each" merely reiterates your original question, which is fixed above.  Decide whether you want a set or a list, make the add/append operation match that, and you should be done.

Comment: It is a set, I am trying to add worm names into it, but I clearly am not doing something right.

Comment: Yes, and I've told you what that is.

Comment: Could explain it a little bit more please I am fairly new to python. I am not trying to be difficult just not sure what to do to make it add stuff to the set without making it a list

Comment: Look up how to add elements to a set.

Comment: so I fixed and was able to get it to sort them but now it repeats still and I am not sure why it won't just work once.

Comment: It won't work just once because you keep telling it to print within another loop.  Again, refer to the answer I gave you, and apply it to your code.